# What is the best way to encrypt my connection string in the web.config?

Tags: encryption

I have a web site written in asp.net 4.0. Right now the connection stirng in the web.config is not encrytped. I pushed it to a host with a web farm. I'm tryign to determine the best way to handle encryption. I don't believe I have any authority on the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an article on the MSDN site that explains how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx